# cannot access partial class of a wsdl

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to call a web service method from a wsdl which contains  a partial class, I am having  problem while accessing this partial class of wsdl in Java. I could not access partial class. After creating web service from this Wsdl in C# and SOAPUI, request and response of any method from this wsdl runs successfully in both C# and SOAPUI. I did not have a problem while sending parameter of partial class because I was able to access them. But in Java I could not access this partial class. Is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Thank you for your advice. I send request like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:service="www.xxxxx.xx"><soapenv:Header>
  <service:SessionInfo>
     <service:UserPassword>?</service:UserPassword>
  </service:SessionInfo></soapenv:Header> <soapenv:Body>
  <service:Method1>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <service:Arguments>
        <service:Parameter1>?</service:Parameter1>
        <service:Parameter2>?</service:Parameter2>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <service:Parameter3>?</service:Parameter3>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <service:Parameter4>?</service:Parameter4>
     </service:Arguments>
  </service:Method1></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the service implementation involves a partial class. There probably is some compatibility issue between the .NET-generated WSDL and Java. But you won't get any useful information until you post your WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the message again comment space was not enough. I am having problem at accessing soapenv:Header part in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Adding header info by using library axis2 is suggested, for this problem. Is there another solution for this problem without using library axis2?